# How do I install imagemagick with homebrew?

Tags: git, gcc, homebrew, osx-lion, gcc4

I'm trying to install Imagemagick on OSX Lion but something is not working as expected.

```
-> brew install imagemagick

/usr/local/git/bin/git
==> Cloning https://github.com/adamv/ImageMagick.git
Cloning into /Users/klebershimabuku/Library/Caches/Homebrew/imagemagick--git...
fatal: https://github.com/adamv/ImageMagick.git/info/refs not found: did you run git      update-server-info on the server?
Error: Failure while executing: git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/adamv/ImageMagick.git /Users/kleber/Library/Caches/Homebrew/imagemagick--git
```

brew doctor says:

```
-> brew doctor
We couldn't detect gcc 4.0.x. Some formulae require this compiler.

Some "config" scripts were found in your path, but not in system or Homebrew folders.

`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if software packagesare installed, and what additional flags to use when compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided script of the same name.

/Users/kleber/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin
passenger-config

Setting DYLD_LIBARY_PATH can break dynamic linking.
You should probably unset it.
```

And yes, I have XCode 4.1 installed and running.

```
-> brew update
From http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: You need to `brew update`; we're using a different mirror for ImageMagick now, and the adamv one is gone.

Comment: I did brew update already. It's already up-to-date.

Comment: You may have to update manually, we have been having issues lately: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues?labels=update-install-issue&sort=updated&direction=desc&state=open&page=1

Comment: Did you reinstall xcode after upgrading to Lion? If you had it installed before hand, that install no longer works. I had the same issue, though not with imagemagick.

Comment: Using the script mentioned there solved. Thank you!

Comment: What script is that exactly? That link points to issues labeled "update-install-issue" and I cannot find a specific force-update script... I'm hesitant to use the script by user478798 (below) since I rather not touch /usr/local/.git

Comment: I got it working following the instructions at the and of this page: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/6994

Comment: @davidhund: i used the script listed in the top answer and it worked great. You don't loose track of packages installed by homebrew in the process.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The quickest fix for me was doing the following:

```
cd /usr/local
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

Then I retried `brew install imagemagick` and it correctly pulled the package from the new mirror, instead of adamv.

If that does not work, ensure that `/Library/Caches/Homebrew` does not contain any imagemagick files or folders. Delete them if it does.

Comment: This won't work anymore today. If you get the issue now, that's because you're trying to install an older version that relies on a now-defunct repo.

Comment: where is the executable?

Comment: sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local ,
cd /usr/local ,
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD ,
brew install imagemagick ,
This works for me today.

Comment: @chovy on a Mac, the executable is called "magick" and will be symlinked at /usr/local/bin/magick to somewhere like /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-8/bin/magick

Answer (score 209):

You could try:

`brew update && brew install imagemagick`

Comment: this worked for me perfectly on mac os 10.11.1 El Capitan

Comment: Note that `brew upgrade` upgrades everything in homebrew.

Answer (score 78):

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Don't forget to install also `gs` which is a dependency if you want to convert pdf to images for example :

```
brew install ghostscript
```

Comment: ghostscript is automatic installed as dependency

Answer (score 8):

Answering old thread here (and a bit off-topic) because it's what I found when I was searching how to install Image Magick on Mac OS to run on the local webserver. It's not enough to brew install Imagemagick. You have to also PECL install it so the PHP module is loaded.

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50364995/467386):

```
brew install php
brew install imagemagick
brew install pkg-config
pecl install imagick
```

And you may need to `sudo apachectl restart`. Then check your `phpinfo()` within a simple php script running on your web server.

If it's still not there, you probably have an issue with running multiple versions of PHP on the same Mac (one through the command line, one through your web server). It's beyond the scope of this answer to resolve that issue, but there are some good options out there.

Answer (score 1):

Got a similar error and fixed by running `brew update` before `brew install imagemagick`

Answer (score -20):

You could do:

```
brew reinstall php55-imagick
```

Where php55 is your PHP version.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but it helped me. I just wanted to know the name of the PHP ImageMagick formula and a search engine lead me here.