# Rails 4 , ImageMagick and PaperClip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i want to upload image i get this error:

```
1 error prohibited this movie from being saved:
Image Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.
```

I have this in Gemfile:

```
gem 'imagemagick-identify', '~> 0.0.1'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.2.1'
```

I ran from my console:  `gem install imagemagick-identify`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`imagemagick-identify` is just a wrapper for imagemagick's `identify` program.  You will need to install imagemagick separately from the gem.

If you are using debian/ubuntu you can do `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`.

If you are on a Mac, you may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053996/how-do-i-install-imagemagick-with-homebrew) helpful.

If you are on Windows, you can find binaries to install [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows).

Looks like there are binaries for other platforms available at the last link as well.

If you have installed imagemagick and still get that error, make sure it is in your PATH.

Comment: I am on cloud9 enviroment. sudo apt-get install imagemagick solved the problem, thanx !

Comment: You may try also: 
`$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick --fix-missing`

Answer (score 5):

if you are using cloud 9 ... there may be times just running

sudo apt-get install imagemagick --fix-missing

wont work. If that is your case, do

sudo apt-get update

first then install imagemagick after that