# ImageMagick ghostscript 'delegate' security policy blocking conversion

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, file-conversion

This seems to be related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion) where there was a [ghostscript bug](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/332928/) and thus ImageMagick devs made a security policy blocking PDF conversion. This was overcome by adjusting the policy file such that rights changed from "none" (by default) to "read | write"

My similar problem is initiated when running a command of the form

```
convert input.pdf output.jpg
```

Now with ghostscript version 9.27 (2019-04-04) and imagemagick version 7.0.8-56 Q16 x86_64 (2019-07-21) (I believe this is the newest version of each), I get this error

```
convert: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `gs' @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/378.
convert: no images defined `output.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3273.
```

So I have sudoedited `/etc/ImageMagick-7/policy.xml` such that the only uncommented lines in the `<policymap>` are changed from

```
<policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="gs" />
```

to

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read | write" pattern="PDF" />
<policy domain="delegate" rights="read | write" pattern="gs" />
```

but the problem persists. Equivalent results if simply commenting out or deleting the above line. This is reproducible on more than one of my Arch machines.

Is there a way to bypass this security policy default? Is it safe to do so?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="gs" />
```

needs to be commented out. This is now noted on the imagemagick page of the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ImageMagick). That page currently cites these bug reports: [FS#59778](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/59778), [FS#62171](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/62171)

For some reason, this didn't immediately work for me. Somehow I got it to work today by moving policy.xml to a backup (deleting), running the convert command, and moving back the original with the line above commented out.

Comment: You also have to change rights="none" to read|write. See my link in my comment below the original post.

Comment: I just tried with current arch linux and this does not fix the issue (for me). I am still getting "convert: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `gs'..." Any current documentation on how to setup convert & ImageMagick & gs correctly on arch / manjaro?

Answer (score 0):

I was having only one of these problems: `convert: no images defined 'output.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3273.`

On my system, this fixed it: `brew install ghostscript`. (via [How do I install imagemagick with homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053996/how-do-i-install-imagemagick-with-homebrew))

I'm using ImageMagick on OSX, installed via homebrew.